# Socket.io: Failed to load resource (404 not found)

Tags: javascript, express, sockets

I created a simple test refer to this tutorial: https://youtu.be/HZWmrt3Jy10
but there is an error: `Failed to load resource: :3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nt3f74j:1 the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

this is server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log(socket);
  console.log('new connection');
}
```

this is sketch.js:

```
socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

this is index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I've tried
[socket.io: Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource)
[Failed to load resource socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024564/failed-to-load-resource-socket-io)
[Failed to load resource - Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059255/failed-to-load-resource-socket-io)
but they all don't work, it seems the socket client does not find socket.io

**#update of the question:**

1. According to the Troubleshooting document of socket.io [Troubleshooting connection issues](https://socket.io/docs/v3/troubleshooting-connection-issues/), I check URL https://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling and the result is `entry not found: /socket.io`, while it should return something like `0{"sid":"Lbo5JLzTotvW3g2LAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}`
2. I try to check whether socket.io is connected and the console output is `connect failedError: xhr poll error`.
   After I check [Consistent "xhr poll error" is caused by hanging instances of XHRPolling](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/250), there should be some problems with socket's connection to the server, but I've no idea how to fix it

```js
console.log(socket.connected);

socket.on('error', function()
{
    console.log("Sorry, there seems to be an issue with the connection!");
});

socket.on('connect_error', function(err)
{
    console.log("connect failed"+err);
});

socket.on('connection', function ()
{
    console.log("connected");
    socket.on('newPhoto',function()
    {
        load_posts();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `socket = io()` instead of `io.connect`

Comment: yes, I've tried, but it doesn't work. Could you have a look at my update, I found some new clues but don't know how to fix it

Comment: In your update you referenced checking `https://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling` while troubleshooting? Did you mean to specify port 3000 there? It is not clear why you would be testing that on port 3001 instead.

Comment: Also is it fair to assume that you have the same version of socket.io installed on the backend (4.4.0)? I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Here's a working example: https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/Web-Sockets-Test#index.js

Comment: try moving `app.use(express.static('public'));` to after the socket initialization

Comment: I'm sorry to cause a misunderstanding. I changed the port later to 3001 as I tried to find if it's a problem

Comment: @Paul Wheeler
https://replit.com/@HaoyueYang/Socket-Test-3#public/sketch.js  could you have a look at my sketch, it's very simple but doesn't work at all

Comment: @Samathingamajig
could you have a look at my example https://replit.com/@HaoyueYang/Socket-Test-3#public/sketch.js  it's simple but I still doesn't know what's the problem

Comment: In order for this project to run on Replit.com the Repl will need to be a Node.js repl not an HTML repl because you need your backend express server to be running and HTML repls don't have a backend running (they only serve static content). Here's an example: https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/Socket-Test-3 It appears that this is successfully connecting to your WebSocket server. The only change I had to make was to move all of your client side files (index.html and sketch.js) into the public folder. I also added nodemon and customized the Repl's run command.